# I'm unable to run github cli commands because I keep running into an Authentication Error. I'm using the correct username and password. Details below

Tags: github, version-control, github-cli

I'm following the steps listed [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github/adding-locally-hosted-code-to-github) to try and link an existing local project to a new repo on GitHub.

I ran `gh repo create` but got an Authentication error, with a note to update my credentials in the .gitsomeconfig file. I ran `gh configure` and entered my GitHub username and my GitHub password (since I chose that option instead of using an authentication token). I entered them exactly the same as I type them in. Then I ran `gh repo create` again and still ran into the Authentication error. I output the content of .gitsomeconfig and verified that the user_login is correct (It doesn't display my password anywhere).

I've tried running `gh configure`at least 6 times now.  I've copied and pasted from Lastpass to be extra sure I'm entering credentials correctly.  I've tried both my username and my email address since I wasn't sure which `gh configure` actually wanted for username, but neither seem to work.  I'm at a loss for what might be going wrong.  Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right command is [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login), using your GitHub account name and your GitHub token (*not* password, your PAT: [Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token), with [scopes](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps) "`admin:org, gist, repo, user, workflow`")

Then you can check with [`gh auth status`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_status).

Once the status is clean (authenticated), you can proceed with other commands, like `gh repo create`.

---

Note that "`authentication failed`" was also be displayed when the remote site timed out. See [`cli/cli` issue 8293](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/8293).

This is fixed with [gh v2.40.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.40.0) and [PR 8337](https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/8337).

Comment: @UncaughtDanError Great! Well done.